Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments ... not found
i'm having NoReverseMatch error message. already spend hours everything looks ok to me but couldn't figure it out. I would appreciate any help. thanks
views.py
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from blog.models import Post

# Create your views here.
def postList(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html',{'posts':posts})
def post_detail(request,year,month,day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, status = Post.Status.DRAFT, slug = post, publish__year=year, publish__month=month, publish__day=day)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post':post} )

urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = "blog"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.postList, name="post_list"),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/', views.post_detail, name="post_detail"),
]

models.py
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = 'DR', 'Draft'
        PUBLISHED = 'PB','Published'
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length= 2, choices=Status.choices, default=Status.DRAFT)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['-publish']),
        ]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:post_detail", args=[self.publish.year, self.publish.month, self.publish.day, self.slug])

list.html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{post.title}}</a>
        <p>{{post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks}}
        <p>{{post.created}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

i wanted to see list of posts with each post title as a link. when the link is clicked i wanted to see the details of that post. it looks like get_absolute_url method in Post model is raising the issue. i'm not sure what other ways to solve the issue. i would appreciate any help. thanks

Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\django\mysite\mysite\blog\models.py", line 39, in get_absolute_url
return reverse('blog:post_detail',
Exception Value: Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '(2024, 7, 12, 'what-is-like-being-immigrant?')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\Z']

You are rendering the template detail.html in your post_detail view whereas you don't seem to have any template with that name in your urls.py. What you have is post_detail.html.
